# How to fix "No line found" exception with scanner if the program doesn't wait for input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Full disclosure, I'm new to java but I couldn't find a fix that worked for my problem.

I'm making a text adventure as practice for school and i'm simply trying to get input from the user using java.util.Scanner which works perfectly in a separate method of the same class while using almost the exact same code.

I keep getting the exception:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

It seems to be because the program isn't waiting for user input.

I tried adding an if else statement to check if there was any input in the scanner when the program should set a string type variable to it's contents and It always comes up empty.

The problem code:

```
System.out.println("In which direction would you like to move?");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String sDirection = reader.nextLine(); //This line specifically.
reader.close();
```

Yet this code works fine:

```
System.out.println("Do you accept this quest?(y/n)");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String sTemp = reader.nextLine();
reader.close();
char answer = sTemp.charAt(0);
return answer;
```

In the problem code the scanner should record the user's input (north, south, east or west), `sDirection` is then set to that string and used in an if else statement. However, the program returns the "No line found" exception before the user gets a chance to input anything.

Comment: the nextLine() automatically waits for input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop closing scanner. When you do this it close underlying stream, so no further reading is possible.

Remove `reader.close();` from all your code.

Also you should create `Scanner` only once and pass it to method which need it.

Comment: why pass it to the method? instantiate it as a class member and it's available for all methods in it

Comment: Sometimes it may read ahead, and cache result, if you dispose one scanner and create another that information will be lost.

Comment: @talex I'm not talking about creating other scanners

Comment: Ups. I don't know how I misinterpret your comment :) Yes. Having it as a class member is other option.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `reader.close();` from your code.

It will work if you want to close the scanner object, you can close where your main method ends and there only you can close it.
And you should create Scanner only once and call it where it needs.!